# Azure App Service metrics vanished

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

I have a App Service that just runs a webjob continuously pulling work off a queue as it arrives. Recently I noticed that the metrics in the App Service blade Overview no longer shows anything:

[image]

I used to have those charts on my dashboard. If I go into the Monitoring and Metrics per instance I can then see the CPU time for the same period as the chart above

[image]

Am I missing something in a setting somewhere? I'm wondering if the metrics in the Overview now only show details for the website and not the webjobs running on the website? Alternatively has all this functionality been moved into the Monitoring area and I should stop using this, shame if so as the monitoring area doesn't appear to give you much control over the time range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this off it appears that Azure was having a bad day as the metrics on the Overview tab have now reappeared after a few days!